# ID становится default, а не generated

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, intellij-idea, spring-boot

Создаю таблицу через IDEA, выставляю параметры для ID: `AUTO INC`, `Primary key`.

На скриншоте можете видеть, что у меня в колонке ID появляется надпись `<default>`, а нужно, чтобы была `<generated>`, что не так? У меня есть другая таблица и там как раз высвечивается `<generated>`, хотя настройки те же самые. БД `Postgresql`.

Хотя делаю по [видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7uxROJ1nduk&ab_channel=EugeneSuleimanov), у него корректно выводит. Таймкод: 59:00

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашей таблице проверьте, чтобы у id были такие атрибуты

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да, именно такие, сейчас Hibernate сам пересоздал и заработало. Руками почему-то не получилось

Comment: Думаю, что это всё равно правильный ответ, если вдруг кто-то будет искать и не поймёт почему ничего не помогает, то советую создать с помощью `Hibernate`, а в файле `appliaction.properties` сделать вот такую строку: `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop` Просто в моём случае, возможно, сам с чем-то напортачил.